# Translating Stephen Poletto SPUserResizableView [Objective C] to Swift 3.0

Tags: objective-c, swift, translation

Using iOS 10.20 & Swift 3.0
Want to use this excellent piece of code written by Stephen Poletto a while back in my code, but need it in Swift 3.0 really.

https://github.com/spoletto/SPUserResizableView

Spent three hours on it today plodding thru, no confidence it will work, but I have to try, must be easier then reinventing the wheel no; anyway got stuck on a few constructs I hope I can find some help on in SO.

I need to translate this ...

```
- (void)resizeUsingTouchLocation:(CGPoint)touchPoint {
// (1) Update the touch point if we're outside the superview.
if (self.preventsPositionOutsideSuperview) {
    CGFloat border = kSPUserResizableViewGlobalInset + kSPUserResizableViewInteractiveBorderSize/2;
    if (touchPoint.x < border) {
        touchPoint.x = border;
    }
```

I got it in Swift, but I fear unlike objective C it seems you cannot change the value of a parameter as he seems to be doing here?

I got ..

```
  func resizeUsingTouchLocation(touchPoint: CGPoint) {
 // (1) Update the touch point if we're outside the superview.
    if (self.preventsPositionOutsideSuperview) {
        let border:CGFloat = CGFloat(kSPUserResizableViewGlobalInset) +    CGFloat(kSPUserResizableViewInteractiveBorderSize) / 2.0;
        if (touchPoint.x < border) {
            touchPoint.x = border
        }
```

It generates an error, cannot change a let property, touchPoint in this case! Got a few more, but these two in particular are phasing me ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Swift, you can not change the input parameters.  Before Swift 3, you could add a `var` before the parameter name and then you'd have a copy that you can modify.  The Swift 3 way is to add `var variableName = variableName` at the top of your function:

```
func resizeUsingTouchLocation(touchPoint: CGPoint) {
    var touchPoint = touchPoint

    // (1) Update the touch point if we're outside the superview.
    if self.preventsPositionOutsideSuperview {
        let border = CGFloat(kSPUserResizableViewGlobalInset) + CGFloat(kSPUserResizableViewInteractiveBorderSize) / 2.0
        if touchPoint.x < border {
            touchPoint.x = border
        }
```

I also removed unneeded type declarations, `()` in `if` statements, and a `;`.